# Scroll a ListView by pixels in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to scroll the a `ListView` in Android by number of pixels. For example I want to scroll the list 10 pixels down (so that the first item on the list has its top 10 pixel rows hidden).

I thought the obviously visible `scrollBy` or `scrollTo` methods on ListView would do the job, but they don't, instead they scroll the whole list wrongly (In fact, the `getScrollY` always return zero even though I have scrolled the list using my finger.)

What I'm doing is I'm capturing Trackball events and I want to scroll the listview smoothly according to the motion of the trackball.

Comment: This is what `scrollby` is supposed to do. Could you post your Java code?

Comment: i think scrollBy somehow messes the listView. i have been experimenting with that one also. it moves the touch events by the scrollBy amount.... so if you set the y scroll by 10 for example the next touch event on the list will be market 10 pixels below the actuall touch location.. sorry i don't know of a better way, but maybe there is a way to compensate for this things with onTouch method on the listView.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The supported way to scroll a `ListView` widget is:

`mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

However since you mentioned specifically that you would like to offset the view vertically, you must call:

`mListView.setSelectionFromTop(position, yOffset);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int,%20int)

Note that you can also use `smoothScrollByOffset(yOffset)`. However it is only supported on API >= 11

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollByOffset(int)

Comment: Also, smoothScroolToPosition is only API >= 8 :(

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the source for the scrollListBy() method added in api 19 you will see that you can use the package scoped `trackMotionScroll` method.

```
public class FutureListView {

    private final ListView mView;

    public FutureListView(ListView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    /**
     * Scrolls the list items within the view by a specified number of pixels.
     *
     * @param y the amount of pixels to scroll by vertically
     */
    public void scrollListBy(int y) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mView.scrollListBy(y);
        } else {
            // scrollListBy just calls trackMotionScroll
            trackMotionScroll(-y, -y);
        }
    }

    private void trackMotionScroll(int deltaY, int incrementalDeltaY) {
        try {
            Method method = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredMethod("trackMotionScroll", int.class, int.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(mView, deltaY, incrementalDeltaY);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ensure that hardware acceleration is on. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code from my `ListView` subclass. It can easily be adapted so it can be used in Activity code.

`getListItemsHeight()` returns the total pixel height of the list, and fills an array with vertical pixel offsets of each item. While this information is valid, `getListScrollY()` returns the current vertical pixel scroll position, and `scrollListToY()` scrolls the list to pixel position.
If the size or the content of the list changes, `getListItemsHeight()` has to be called again.

```
private int m_nItemCount;
private int[] m_nItemOffY;

private int getListItemsHeight() 
{  
    ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();  
    m_nItemCount = adapter.getCount();
    int height = 0;
    int i;

    m_nItemOffY = new int[m_nItemCount];

    for(i = 0; i< m_nItemCount; ++i){ 
        View view  = adapter.getView(i, null, this);  

        view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));  

        m_nItemOffY[i] = height;
        height += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }  

    return height;  
}  

private int getListScrollY()
{
    int pos, nScrollY, nItemY;
    View view;

    pos = getFirstVisiblePosition();
    view = getChildAt(0);
    nItemY = view.getTop();
    nScrollY = m_nItemOffY[pos] - nItemY;

    return nScrollY;
}

private void scrollListToY(int nScrollY)
{
    int i, off;

    for(i = 0; i < m_nItemCount; ++i){
        off = m_nItemOffY[i] - nScrollY;
        if(off >= 0){
            setSelectionFromTop(i, off);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, ListViewCompat is probably a better solution.

```
android.support.v4.widget.ListViewCompat.scrollListBy(@NonNull ListView listView, int y)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move by pixels then u can use this

```
public void scrollBy(ListView l, int px){
    l.setSelectionFromTop(l.getFirstVisiblePosition(),l.getChildAt(0).getTop() - px);
}
```

this works for even ones with massive headers