# Android scroll list programmatically with animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want to scroll a list view by x pixels

`list.scrollListBy(x)` works, but the default scrolling animations are missing

Is there any api to scroll list with animation,

I cannot use `smoothScrollBy` and its other varients, because it wont scroll if the element is already visible.

Comment: have you any example of what you whan..???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll a ListView by pixels in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375084/scroll-a-listview-by-pixels-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Smooth)ScrollToPosition doesn't work properly with RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845742/smoothscrolltoposition-doesnt-work-properly-with-recyclerview)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using RecyclerView, you can call the method

```
list.scrollToPosition(int position)
```

to scroll to a particular position on the list. Let's say there are 50 positions on the list, and your phone screen is showing first 10 positions of the list. Then you can call

```
list.scrollToPosition(40);
```

to scroll to the 40th position. There will be a **slightly smooth effect**.

Comment: list = LinearLayoutManager